# Get my twitter timeline instead of public twitter timeline using Node JS

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

This code works fine but it seems that it retrieve any tweet not only the people I follow, I want to get my timeline tweets
what should I do ?

```
var open = require('open');
var sys = require('sys');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var OAuth= require('oauth').OAuth;
var express = require("express");
var util   = require('./util');
var app = express();

var oa = new OAuth(
  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
  "NeFpQZNDapDtFJnUXDe0Q",
  "mXf7AKYJWIdiToKuSgsTm2me0GBA1aNn39uskmEoOM",
  "1.0",
  "http://127.0.0.1:8080/twitterCallback",
  "HMAC-SHA1"
);
var oauthtoken ,oauthtokensecret;
{
  oa.getOAuthRequestToken(function(error, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, results){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.send("yeah no. didn't work.")
    }
    else {
      oauthtoken = oauth_token;
      oauthtokensecret = oauth_token_secret;      
      open('http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token='+oauthtoken);
    } 

  });
}

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
function readFile(fileName,response){
  fs.readFile(fileName, function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  response.end(data);
});
}

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  if(req.url == '/favicon.ico'){
      res.end('Hello Http');
   }else if(req.url.indexOf('twitterCallback') != -1){

      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end('Hello Http');
      var url = require('url');
      var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
      var query = url_parts.query;
      var oauth_verifier = query.oauth_verifier;
      console.log(oauth_verifier);
      oa.getOAuthAccessToken(oauthtoken,oauthtokensecret,query.oauth_verifier, function(error, oauth_access_token, oauth_access_token_secret, results)
        {
          if (error){
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            //console.log("oauth_access_token = " + oauth_access_token);
            //console.log("oauth_access_token_secret = " + oauth_access_token_secret);
          }
          var twitter = require('ntwitter');

          var twit = new twitter({
            consumer_key: 'NeFpQZNDapDtFJnUXDe0Q',
            consumer_secret: 'mXf7AKYJWIdiToKuSgsTm2me0GBA1aNn39uskmEoOM',
            access_token_key: oauth_access_token,
            access_token_secret: oauth_access_token_secret
          });

          twit.stream('statuses/sample', function(stream) {
            stream.on('data', function (data) {
              console.log(data.text);
            });
          });

        }

      );
    }else{
      readFile(req.url.substr(1));
    }
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ntwitter library : https://github.com/AvianFlu/ntwitter

And to consume api :

```
var twitter = require('ntwitter');

var twit = new twitter({
    consumer_key: 'Twitter',
    consumer_secret: 'API',
    access_token_key: 'keys',
    access_token_secret: 'go here'
});

twit.stream('user', {track:'nodejs'}, function(stream) {
    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    stream.on('end', function (response) {
        // Handle a disconnection
    });
    stream.on('destroy', function (response) {
        // Handle a 'silent' disconnection from Twitter, no end/error event fired
    });
    // Disconnect stream after five seconds
    setTimeout(stream.destroy, 5000);
});
```

Comment: I think stream will only get new tweets, what if we need last 20 or 30 tweets from user timeline, and how can we get 30 more tweets following the previous tweets.